# How To copy a webform from a existing form in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I  have a existing webform and i want to make a copy of same and then i want to edit it. Sorry for the dumb question but i am totally new in this .
please help me.

Comment: Did you try: http://www.ehow.com/how_8668265_copy-webform-drupal.html ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Node clone` module for that https://www.drupal.org/project/node_clone